# PHP query difference between 2 rows MySql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello i am looking for a way to make the difference between 2 rows in Mysql query

```
datetime             | value
2016-01-04 10:00:00  | 50 
2016-01-04 11:00:00  | 60 
2016-01-04 13:00:00  | 65
```

The result i m looking for is:

```
datetime             | value
2016-01-04 10:00:00  | 0 
2016-01-04 11:00:00  | 10 
2016-01-04 13:00:00  | 5
```

How can i obtain this result by php please?

Comment: Please give us your code to work with, both PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery.  Note that this will return `NULL` for the first difference:

```
select t.*,
       (t.value -
        (select t2.value
         from t t2
         where t2.datetime < t.datetime
         order by t2.datetime desc
         limit 1
        )
       ) as diff
from t;
```

It is easy enough to convert the `NULL` to `0`, but I prefer the `NULL` value because the previous value is not meaningful.

Comment: Order-by is also necessary in the outer query.

Comment: Perfect !  Thanks Guys